# wpf canvas get child name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I got a canvas with some children.

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas" MouseDown="getElements">
    <Rectangle  Height="200" Width="200" Name="Element1"/>
    <Rectangle  Height="200" Width="200" Name="Element2"/>
</Canvas>
```

and by clicking on a canvas element I want to get the name of the clicked element with something like this:

```
public void getElements(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DependencyObject dpobj = Sender as DependencyObject;
     string name = dpobj.GetValue(FrameworkContentElement.NameProperty) as string;

     Console.WriteLine("Element Clicked: " + name);
}
```

but I only get the name of the canvas. can anybody help me to get the names of the clicked elements?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `MouseDown` is routed event instead of `EventArgs` use `RoutedEventArgs` or for `MouseDown` you can use `MouseButtonEventArgs`. It will give you `OriginalSource` property and you can try getting `Name` of `e.OriginalSource`:

```
private void getElements(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var elementName = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event is routed from the elements in the canvas. To get the original source you can use the RoutedEventArgs instead:

```
public void getElements(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dpobj = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
    string name = dpobj.GetValue(FrameworkContentElement.NameProperty) as string;

    Console.WriteLine("Element Clicked: " + name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Event Handler for the MouseLeftButtonUp event on your Canvas (as WPF uses Routed Events, the event will 'bubble' up to parents and will be raised there, too). The XAML code would look somewhat like this:

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasChildren.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas MouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" Height="200" Width="200" Name="Element1" Fill="LightBlue"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="100" Height="200" Width="200" Name="Element2" Fill="DarkSalmon"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

In your code behind file, you can retrieve the original object that was clicked by accessing the `Source` property of the event arguments, like shown in this code:

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var rectangle = (Rectangle) e.Source;
    var name = rectangle.Name;
}
```

You can download my full example [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14810011/CanvasChildren.zip) (it's a Dropbox link).